# eth0 not starting on boot after Virtualbox clone

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, clone, mac-address

After cloning my CentOS VM in Virtualbox (I used the `Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards` option), the original and the clone VM both now has `127.0.0.1` as their IP.

Anyone knows how to fix it?
The vbox's IP used to follow my network's IP (i.e., if host is `192.168.0.2` then the vbox is `192.168.0.3` but now the vboxes is both `127.0.0.1`)
I am using `Bridged Adapter` BTW.

EDIT:
OK, I now realize eth0 is not running on start up. My question now is how enable eth0 on startup? Note that it used to start automatically before I performed the clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your this question `how enable eth0 on startup?`

Open `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file in that

change `ONBOOT=no`

To

`ONBOOT=yes`

Answer (score 5):

I just find from on other another site, you need to edit the file name 70-persistent-net.rules under /etc/udev/rules.d/ change the MAC address to match with the clone VM virtualbox

so edit two files

1. /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
2. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 -- from heavyd

change the MAC address in both files to match with the VM VirtualBox assign if you click on the right click cloneVMvirutalBox=>Setting=>Network=>Adapter 1 tap there is a Advanced will provide the MAC address.

Hope this will help when some one come across this site.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS ties the network configuration script to a specific MAC address, so when you changed your MAC address you essentially broke the script.  You can fix it by editing the script as root:

```
sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

In the script look for the line `HWADDR` line.  Update the value to match your new MAC address and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In Virtual Machine settings, remove the network card and reinstall it.
Restart the VM if needed

check your device name with

```
ip link show
```

It should work now.